# Preventing a Stuck Sparge

Tags: sparge, wort, lauter, mash

What steps pre-mash can be taken to limit the likelihood of a stuck sparge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Get the right crush

This is the single most important thing to prevent a stuck sparge. Read the HomebrewTalk's wiki page on [evaluating the crush](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Evaluating_the_Crush).  An ideal milling breaks the internal bits of grain into a coarse powder while leaving the bulk of the husks intact. It is the husks that do the most to set up a good filter.

[image: Close-up of a good crush]
<sub>(source: [homebrewtalk.com](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/images/thumb/f/f0/Crush_moist_normal_closeup.jpg/315px-Crush_moist_normal_closeup.jpg))</sub>   [full size](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Image:Crush_moist_normal_closeup.jpg)

### Use a good manifold design

A large area covered by the manifold or pick-up, spaced evenly across the bed. A few, or a single, pick-up may lead to channeling, which compacts the grain bed. John Palmer covers this topic in his book *[How to Brew](http://www.howtobrew.com/appendices/appendixD-1.html)*. His findings are the result of experiments he designed with fish tanks and dyed water.

[image: MLT flow rates]
<sub>(source: [howtobrew.com](http://www.howtobrew.com/images/f173.gif))</sub>

### Other things

- **Sparge slowly** Take at least 30 minutes to rinse the grainbed.
- **Mash out** Raising the mash temperature (168°F) not only stops enzymatic reactions, it makes the mash liquid flow more easily.
- **Keep the grainbed wet** Always have an inch or two of water above the grainbed. If you let sparge water run too low the top may compress.
- **Rice hulls** Available at most any LHBS, they add no flavor and increase the filtering capability of the grainbed. After you crush, mix the rice hulls into the grain.

Comment: I want to  brew with you.

Comment: It is extraordinarily glamorous to brew with me. ;-) Just give me two weeks notice before you knock on my door.  Or, I'm going to NHC & GABF this year. You?

Comment: I live in Denver. So GABF for sure. I might try to hold a Breakfast and Brewing that week.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I have noticed with some of the recipe kits is that they don't always separate the adjuncts from the grain. Running flaked maize, wheat or oats through a mill is a guaranteed stuck sparge. Make sure that the more non-grain ingredients in the recipe the more attention you pay to volume, mash thickness, sparge temperature and flow rates. I think its mentally less frustrating to deal with if you know from the recipe that the probability of getting stuck is higher. Rice hulls are a must, get a big bag and keep them around.

Comment: Good point about thickness. More water in the tun helps prevnt the onset of a stuck sparge.  By the time you finish vorlauf the grainbed should be well set and thickness matters less. I disagree about keeping rice hulls on hand. I've never had to use them. Never had a stuck sparge.